# Pass Java Components as arguments when creating an instance

Tags: java, swing

This might be a dumb question, but I'm trying to teach myself Java, so I'm pretty much new to Java.  I'm trying to pass a JButton as an argument when I'm creating an instance; I'm not sure if it is possible, and I searched online with no luck.
Here is an easy example:

```
public class Buttons extends JButton {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JButton buttonOpen;

public Buttons(JButton button, String string) {
    buttonOpen = button;
    button.setText(string);
}
}
```

here is the Panel class

```
      import javax.swing.JPanel;


      public class Panel extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JPanel panelCustomerInfo;

public Panel() {

    Buttons open = new Buttons(the component go here, "Open");
    panelCustomerInfo.add(open);

}
```

}

Comment: Why does `Buttons` extends `JButton`?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to create one file per component instead of creating one big file that has all Java components such as buttons, panels, labels. For example, one class for buttons, one class for labels, and so on. Do you see where I'm getting at?

Comment: @user1183022: You can pass a reference to any object so long as it's appropriate for the parameter type. You haven't shown where you try to actually use it...

Comment: I'm trying to get the class small and not a lot of code in it

Comment: Use panels for that. Buttons are not Swing containers.

Comment: hold on...I'm going to edit my question

Comment: Stop extending Classes, unless you not modifying their behaviour in any manner. Simply use a `JButton button = new JButton();` instead of creating a whole class for JButton, make a single method that returns a `JButton`, that will be more useful.

Comment: Making your classes small and each responsible for a single purpose is usually a good thing. But I am not so sure whether organizing a UI by grouping Widgets of the same type in separate classes makes much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you want to extend JPanel ?
Just import the swing package and use it within your methods.

Something is wrong about this set constructor

```
 public Buttons(JButton button, String string) {
     buttonOpen = button;
     button.setText(string); 
 }
```

this should be like this I think:

```
 public Buttons(JButton button, String string) {
     buttonOpen = button;
     buttonOpen.setText(string); 
}
```

Comment: Ok, I got that part, but how do I declare an instance? For example, Buttons button = new Buttons(I want to know what goes here, "Text");

Comment: I know what goes in the parameter, but I don't know how.

Comment: check out the constructors for JButton [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html)